# Formtastic belongs_to select tag generates a blank selection option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations, formtastic

I'm using Formtastic as a semantic_form_for books and lists. Each list `has_many` books and each book `belongs_to` a list. When the user creates a new book, they can choose what list to add the book to. Here is my form code:

```
<%= semantic_form_for(@book) do |f| %>
    <p>Select a list to add this book to: </p>
    <%= f.input :list, :as => :select %>
    ...
    <%= f.submit "Add book", class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

The only problem is that the select tag that is generated has a blank option for select at the top. So the options for select look like this:

- [blank]
- List 1
- List 2
- List 3

  etc.

I don't want there to be an extra space. How can I fix that?

Here is a picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `include_blank`. So it'd be something like this: `<%= f.input :list, :as => :select, :include_blank => false %>`